# text mining with R: how to see positive-negative sentiments in my document?

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am new to R. I have found the number of positive-negative words (953 negative, 458 positive) in my document, but I want to see these words. How can I do it?

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(glue)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
davos <- read_file("davos.txt")
fileText <- glue(read_file(davos))
fileText <- gsub("\\$", "", fileText)
tokens <- data_frame(text = fileText) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)
tokens %>% inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% count(sentiment) %>% spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)

# Joining, by = "word"
#
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     negative positive sentiment
#        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#   1     953.     458.     -495.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
library(tidy_text)
fileText <- "Sometimes I'm happy, sometimes I'm sad"
tokens <- data_frame(text = fileText) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)
tokens %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    word sentiment
#   <chr>     <chr>
# 1 happy  positive
# 2   sad  negative
```

Comment: @EmrahBILGIC if the solution solved your problem don't forget to accept it